# Android requirement to run bluetooth in app

Tags: bluetooth

Im trying to create an app which makes use of bluetooth to send scoring information between the device and the toy. Im trying to make the app works on as many different devices as possible.

1). May i know what android version is required at least for sending data through bluetooth?

2). Can i store my app user date like scoring,date and time of gameplay and their account information on Google Cloud? If not, where should i find a server to store my database?

3). (It may sound stupid but just to confirm) Is there a need to scale my ui buttons according to different screen sizes and device?